# Is there a way to define a generic for Svelte store's Update?

Tags: typescript, svelte, typescript-generics, svelte-store

I was looking at this section [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Svelte_TypeScript#Using_Svelte_stores_with_generics) about typescript generics in svelte, and it mentions that

> Svelte stores support generics out of the box

In my project, I added a generic to a store item like so

```
interface Car {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

export const cars = writable<Array<Car>>([])
```

However, when I use `update` like this

```
      cars.update(c) => [
        ...c,
        {      
          x: 1,
          y: 2,
          BAD: "BAD"
        },
      ]);
```

Typescript does not complain. This also occurs for `set`, the method just has an `any` type.

Comment: The element you add to the `cars` store array is technically of a subtype to `Car` since [Typescript uses structural typing instead of nominal typing to determine type equality](https://medium.com/@lemoine.benoit/why-does-typescript-sometimes-fails-to-type-check-extra-properties-fd230ebbc295).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, as [@Tholle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3617886/tholle) pointed out ala this [article](https://medium.com/@lemoine.benoit/why-does-typescript-sometimes-fails-to-type-check-extra-properties-fd230ebbc295), I need to be more explicit because of Typescripts structural typing, so to get the intended result I had to type my return, like this.

```
 cars.update(c): Array<Car> => [
        ...c,
        {      
          x: 1,
          y: 2,
          BAD: "BAD"
        },
      ]);
```